# Java regex emptyString only numbers and . or , numbers required

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to develop a simple REGEX in Java without success so far. Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

1. An empty String is not accepted. At least one group of numbers is required in the left side or the right side of the separator digit. `13.` is accepted; `.13` is accepted as well.
2. The separator might be `.` or `,`.
3. Only one or zero character separator appearance is allowed.
4. A separator character alone without numbers is not allowed. For example, `.` is not allowed alone.

The main problem I am facing is how I can make the separator optional. I am trying this:

```
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]*.?|,?[0-9]*$");
```

Here i am trying to specify a list of numbers at the start of the string which are optional. Later, I specify a separator character, which may be `.` or `,` which are optional as well. Later, the right side, also a string of numbers, and also optional. Here is the problem: only a `.` or a empty string is matching.

Here is my code:

```
    Matcher matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);// a empty string should not be matching
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());
    input="a";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);//true how can i fix this letter should not be allowed....
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());
    input="13.";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);//returns true is OK.
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());        
    input=".13";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);//returning false why is this if . is a character separator allowed.
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());
    input="13.,";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);//false is OK only one separator might be specify.
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());        
    input=",.13";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);//false is OK only one separator might be specify.
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());        
    input="13,";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);//true is OK only one separator might be specify. , in this case
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());        
    input=",13";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());//true is ok the separator is , in this case
    input="1131313133";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());//true only numbers        
    input="113.1313.133.13";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());//false is OK only one appeareance of the separator is allowed.        
    input="1131313133.132313";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());//false why is this... please help
    input=".";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches()); //true how can i fix this i need a left or right sequence of numbers.       
    input=".....";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());//false is OK
    input=",,,,,,,";
    matcher = clazz.pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(input+" "+matcher.matches());//false is OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem, among others, is that, because of operator precedence

```
^[0-9]*.?|,?[0-9]*$
```

is basically the same as

```
(^[0-9]*.?)|(,?[0-9]*$)
```

So `digits.digits` won't match.

And `[0-9]*` means zero or more, so just `.` will match.

Also note that `^` and `$` aren't actually required in this case, it's more for when you're using `find()` or similar.

**What you want is probably something more like:**

```
[0-9]+[.,]?|[0-9]*[.,][0-9]+
```

`[.,]` means either `.` or `,`.
`[0-9]+` means **one** or more digits.
Seems your familiar with the other syntax.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**EDIT:**

Also note that for numbers you may not want `00000` to match, although not stated in the requirements. So something like:

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]*)[.,]?|(0|[1-9][0-9]*)?[.,][0-9]+
```

The above would match either a `0` or any number that doesn't start with a zero to the left of the optional separator (or nothing if there's something to the right of the separator).

Comment: @user1119974 Remember to [upvote and/or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) this answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Also note that for numbers you may not want 00000 to match, but this wasn't stated in the requirements. wow that would be useful can you help again..

Comment: wow awesome hey guys i am new to stackoverflow how can i close the question or marked as solved.

Comment: @user1119974 [Accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) basically means marking as solved.